# log4j 2 configuration Issue

Tags: log4j2

in the config file how to separate the package in different appaender using asynch
i have two different package and using different appender i want separate log output
first two appender is different package and third appender is different one
and i need all appender connect to asynch...
pls help me to solve this

here my config file..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration strict="true" status="WARN">

    <appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="Logger/knight.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </File>
        <File name="Except"  fileName="log1/Execption9.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </File>
        <Async name="Async">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
            <appender-ref ref="MyFile" />
            <appender-ref ref="Except" />
        </Async>

    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="all">
            <appender-ref ref="Async" />
        </root>

    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure three separate AsyncAppenders, one for each of the File appenders, and one for console, then configure root as:

```
  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="async-console" level="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="async-file1" level="trace" />
    <appender-ref ref="async-file2" level="error" />
  </root>
```

But this solution gives you three threads. Why not use AsyncLoggers (using the selector command line option, see the docs for AsyncLoggers)?
That way you only have one logging thread, and it is probably a lot faster too...

Comment: ya now im using AsyncLogger its working...but i have some doubts

Comment: ya now im using AsyncLogger its working...but i have some doubts    1.What is the difference between Logger and root? im little bit confused about dis..                                        2.if i have one exception in my class i want to  that log message separately ...any idea about dis????

Comment: Root is the default (fallback) logger. Named loggers will match on the name you used when creating the Logger in your code. For example, your code has: Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("my.package.MyClass");                       - in the config, <logger name="my.package" additivity="false" level="error">... will send all ERROR level logs to Loggers whose name starts with "my.package" to a separate appender. Take a look at the log4j2 docs on additivity for more examples and details.

Comment: i have one more doubt how to configure log4j2 into jboss 5